# opening number of files in vim found using find

Tags: vim, find

I do,

```
find . -type f -name '*.c'
```

to find the list of .c files in my project. I want to open them all in the vim. I did something like this.

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | xargs -- vim
```

It was not ideal. Is this correct or is there a better way. Please do not ask me to install a vim plugin. I am looking for unix way of doing things, i.e, by piping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vim $(find . -type f -name '*.c')
```

should work, at least if none of your `.c` files have special characters in their names. 
Depending on what shell you're using (bash, csh, etc...), you might need to change that to

```
vim `find . -type f -name '*.c'`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The first way was definitely better.